# Overlay on window.history.go(-1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay, back, browser-history

I want to accomplish this:

When a user get to our page via Google Ad-words and is going to leave it through the back button in his browser, I want to show him an rendered overlay with some stuff in it("Can't find whatcha looking for? Call us, we'll help you!"... blah blah). Of course the user can close it and go back to Google.

Is there any whey to get an event-handler which get called when the user is pressing the "back"-button in his browser, so I can pop-up my own Popup? :-)

Also: this should not affect pressing links or reloading the page.

greetings from Germany

Comment: If you find a way - let me know. ^^ But I think it's not possible without the standard alert window - you can only add something but not replace the alert...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a div that will be your overlay and a dialog box that contains the information you want to display to the user. When your event is triggered, use the jquery.show() to display the overlay and the dialog box.

You could try something like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style type="text/css">
           #fullscreen { display:none; position: fixed; z-index:500;  min-height: 100%;  min-width: 1024px;  width: 100%; height: auto; background-color: #565656; top:0; left:0px; margin:0; padding:0; opacity: .5;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50)";  filter: alpha(opacity=50);}      
           #myDialog {display:none;}
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="fullscreen"></div>
      <div id="myDialog title="My Dialog Title" ></div>
   </body>

   <script type="text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function () {
    //When the user attempts to navigate away from the current page...
    $(window).unload(function () {
        $('fullscreen').show();

            $(function () {
                $("#myDialog ").dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    closeOnEscape: false,
                    width: 660,
                    modal: true,
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                        //hide close button.
                        $(this).parent().children().children('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
                    },
                    buttons: {
                        "OK": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            $("fullscreen").hide();
                            window.location = "http://mypage.com";
                        },
                        "No, thanks": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            $("fullscreen").hide();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
       });
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Then do any needed actions. If you are unfamiliar with these aspects of jQuery, I recommend taking a look at the documentation for dialogs: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your fast response,
I think I didn't made myself clear enough: Its not about the overlay more about the how to prevent the user from "getting back" to Google.